# Use angular flexlayout conditionally?

Tags: angular-flex-layout

In a conditional sense.  So, if the screen is a certain size, set an attribute

Pseudo-code:

```
<mat-sidenav class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true"
    [opened]="! (fxLayout.xs | fxLayout.sm)">
</mat-sidenav>
```

So, if the screen size is small, then sidenav should not be opened by default.

Is this possible?  Perhaps using `ngIf`, but I can't think of a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achive such behaviour by using [MediaObserver::isActive()](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/MediaObserver#2-mediaobserverisactive)

first, inject `MediaObserver` service:

```
...
constructor(public mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {}
...
```

then use it in your template as follows:

```
<mat-sidenav class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true"
    [opened]="!(mediaObserver.isActive('xs') || mediaObserver.isActive('sm'))">
</mat-sidenav>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a perfect solution!